# Is it possible to have a function within a method in Python?

Tags: python, function, methods, functional-programming

If so, how would you do this.

def methodname(self, blah, blah)
^how do I place a function inside this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just stick a `def` inside. You can even nest whole classes inside functions and methods:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method(self, bar):
        def inner(magic):
            class Madness(object):
                def __init__(inself, foo): inself.foo = foo
            return Madness(magic)
        return inner(bar)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got a " local variable 'method' referenced before assignment " error when I did this.

Comment: It is good practice to call the the self in inner classes something else, e.g. this or me, so it doesn't conflict with the self of the outer class.

Comment: @thebjorn: good call. @RahulSharma: works for me (try `Foo().method(3)`)